# QMouseEvent' object has no attribute 'pos'

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt6

I'm having some problems here with PyQT6 while i try to move a image label trought the screen.

I'm trying to move a label that is in a Scrollabel Area to a frame, and i get the following error: "PyQT6: 'QMouseEvent' object has no attribute 'pos' "

Here is the code:

```
class DraggableLabel(QLabel):
    def init(self, parent, image):
        super(QLabel, self).init(parent)
        pixmap = QPixmap(image)
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(120, 120)

        self.setPixmap(pixmap)
        # self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButtons.LeftButton:
            # print('Evento: ', event.screenPos())
            self.drag_start_position = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not (event.buttons() & Qt.MouseButtons.LeftButton):
            return
        if (event.pos() - self.drag_startposition).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return

        drag = QDrag(self)
        mimedata = QMimeData()
        mimedata.setText(self.text())
        mimedata.setImageData(self.pixmap().toImage())

        drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
        painter = QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.grab())
        painter.end()
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
        drag.exec(Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction)
```

Edit

Traceback:

```
PS C:\Users\doug\Projetos> & C:/Python/python.exe c:/Users/doug/Projetos/main.py
qt.gui.imageio: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\doug_\Projetos\lib\sys_functions.py", line 25, in mousePressEvent
    self.drag_start_position = event.pos()
AttributeError: 'QMouseEvent' object has no attribute 'pos'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error in your post.

Comment: @ewong Done. Trackeback was inserted

Comment: `PyQt6` can be different then `PyQt5` and it may have different names or elements. You could use `print( dir(event) )` to see all function avaliable in `event`

Comment: using Google I found that now it may be `.position()` - [About PyQt6 and PySide6](https://www.mfitzp.com/forum/t/about-pyqt6-and-pyside6/744/4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt6 has refactored the event inputs API to adapt to new technologies (read https://www.qt.io/blog/input-events-in-qt-6 for more information) so it has introduced new base classes such as QSinglePointEvent from which QMouseEvent inherits that have the `position()` method that returns the position of the event (in this case the mouse). Even so, Qt6 has the `pos()` method that is redundant but is maintained for compatibility but it seems that PyQt6 has eliminated it which seems like a bug since PySide6 still maintains it having compatibility with Qt6. So in this case you should use `position()` instead of `pos()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found and modified a similar piece of PyQt5 code, author = "Deokyu Lim", to PySide6:

```py
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent):
        
        if e.buttons() != Qt.RightButton:
            return

        mime_data = QMimeData()
        mime_data.setData("application/hotspot",
                          b"%d %d" % (e.position().x(), e.position().y()))

        drag = QDrag(self)
        
        drag.setMimeData(mime_data)
        
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
        self.render(pixmap)
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

        drag.setHotSpot(e.position().toPoint() - self.rect().topLeft())
        drag.exec(Qt.MoveAction)
```

And `e.position()` had the wrong signature in PySide6 and required to be `e.position().toPoint()` for the code to be acceptable and function.  As I haven't earned the comment privilege, I have added this answer.  Maybe this isn't correct but the solution above appeared to work correctly and may be helpful to others.